# Django Transactions, select_for_update, concurrent modification?

Tags: django, transactions, django-views

I have a bunch of views where I check if certain conditions are true before executing. It doesn't matter which view is executed first, but I'm concerned about one user using a view that changes the data after the condition has been checked in another view.  Would appreciate any help on this.

I'm using the 2 scoops suggestion of setting ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True, to wrap each request in a transaction. My site is relatively low-traffic so I'm not concerned about performance yet. Using postgres as well.

```
def feed_dog(self, dog_id):
    dog = get_objects_or_404(Dog, pk=dog_id)
    if not dog.removed and not dog.fed_today:    # line 3
        # do additional checks
        dog.fed_today = True    # line 5
        dog.save()
        # also modify other related objects
        treat = Treats.objects.last()
        treat.dogs_being_fed_with_this_treat.add(dog)
        treat.save()

def remove_dog_from_feed_list(self, dog_id):
    dog = get_objects_or_404(Dog, pk=dog_id)
    if not dog.fed_today           # line 12
    dog.removed = True
    dog.save()
    treat.dogs_being_fed_with_this_treat.remove(dog)
    treat.save()
```

So my concern is that someone calls the feed_dog view, and then after line 3 is checked but before line 5 is started, another user calls the remove_dog function. Since dog.fed_today is False still when user 2 is calling remove_dog, line 12 is True, and remove_dog view goes ahead and does dog.removed = True. At the same time the feed_dog view continues and sets dog.fed_today=True, adds the dog to the treat array, etc. So then I have an inconsistent state of dog.removed = True, and dog.fed_today = True.

Basically I need it so that certain attributes on the Dog model can't both be True at the same time, like dog.fed_today =True and dog.removed=True. I also have this related model Treat, where I don't want a dog object to have removed = True and also be in the treat.dogs_being_fed array.

Q:Is this a valid concern? Since transactions provide isolation, doesn't it mean that 1 of these views accesses the data either all before or all after the other one (they can't see the data in the half-done state)?

Q:Would it help to increase the isolation property of Django/Postgres from Read Committed?

Q:Would it help to have constraints on the Dog model itself (like having a def clean method that says a Dog can't be both removed=True and fed_today = True?). I'm mostly checking things in the views. Would this get reflected in a transaction? Would I also be able to create a constraint that reflects attributes in multiple models, like can't have dog.removed=True and have that dog be in the Treats.dogs_being_fed array?

Q:What's the purpose of select_for_update, and would it help here? If transactions are already supposed to provide isolation, what's the purpose of select_for_update?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really can't use transactions effectively unless you understand database isolation levels. If you're using PostgreSQL, check out [their documentation on the subject](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html).

To answer your specific questions:

*Is this a valid concern?*

Absolutely. The default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level will not protect the database from your code above.

*Since transactions provide isolation, doesn't it mean that one of these views accesses the data either all before or all after the other one (they can't see the data in the half-done state)?*

No. That is approximately what the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level means, though.

*Would it help to increase the isolation property of Django / Postgres from `READ COMMITTED`?*

Yes, but you generally don't need the stricter isolation levels, and since there are performance penalties for using them it usually makes more sense to rethink your database access patterns.

*Would it help to have constraints on the `Dog` model itself (like having a `clean()` method)?*

No. Django's validation methods are applied to the Python objects created after the database has been queried. They won't help to prevent data corruption caused by race conditions. (They might help to *detect* it after the fact, though.)

*If transactions are already supposed to provide isolation, what's the purpose of `select_for_update()`?*

[`select_for_update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) performs a `SELECT` but locks the matching rows so that they can't be concurrently modified in other transactions. As mentioned, that is not what transaction isolation levels do.

*Would it help here?*

Yes! That is the simplest solution to your problem, since you are selecting (and can lock) a single row in the `Dog` table. If both functions use

```
dog = Dog.objects.filter(pk=dog_id).select_for_update().get()
```

then they will both try to lock the row in question. If there is an attempt at concurrent modification, the second one will wait until the first transaction has ended before continuing.

Comment: Thanks, I so appreciate it.  A few questions about select_for_update:      1)what's the purpose of this nowait=False setting; when would I want to make this true? Don't I always want to have nowait=False so that other views have to wait for view to finish?   2)if I have other views that just access Dog.objects.all(), like to display all Dog objects but don't modify any of the Dog objects, will those views also have to wait until one of the views I'm using select_for_update in finish?

Comment: Also,  3)3)Do you happen to know how I can test concurrent access doing a python unit test or Selenium test?  LIke how can I have a selenium test where two browsers try to modify the code at the same time and I can test that the Dog object doesn't end up in an incompatible state after both views are run?

Comment: @user3048472: 1) `nowait` determines how Django and the database react when there is a conflict. If `nowait=False` (the usual case, and probably what you want), the process will block and wait for the conflict to finish before continuing. If `nowait=True`, a `DatabaseError` will be raised and you'll have to decide how to proceed (e.g. give up, try again, etc.). 2) No, they will not wait. But the transaction isolation will keep them from seeing the object in an inconsistent state. 3) You should post a separate question if you're having trouble with that.

Comment: Thanks again, I'll search for 3) and see if I can find the answer.  I posted a quick question about using select_for_update and select_related in the same query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253793/django-select-for-update-and-select-related-on-same-query)