# django select_for_update and select_related on same query?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

Does anyone know if you can do both the .select_for_update() and .select_related() statements in a single query? Such as:

```
employee = get_object_or_404(Employee.objects.select_for_update().
                              select_related(‘company’), pk=3)
```

It seemed to work fine in one place in my code, but a second usage threw an "InternalError: current transaction is aborted" for a series of unit tests. Removing the .select_related and leaving just .select_for_update made the error go away, but I don't know why. I'd like to use them both to optimize my code, but if forced to choose, I'll pick select_for_update.  Wondering if there's a way I can use both. Using postgres and django 1.9. Thanks!

Comment: Try to do it in transaction wrapper.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm using ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True in my settings.py so all my views should be in a Transaction. So I don't think that's the problem?

Comment: I had the same problem, you are probably getting a `DatabaseError: FOR UPDATE cannot be applied to the nullable side of an outer join` error back from postgres, obscured by being part of a call to a view in the test.  It seems `select_related` and `select_for_update` are incompatible. See here http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.58.0511142229050.12705@linuxworld.com.au (and the reply)

Comment: Thank you! That's awesome.  If you want the reputation points, go ahead and post that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 18):

Since Django 2.0, you **can** use `select_for_update` together with `select_related` even on nullable relations - by [using new parameter `of=...`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update)

Using their `Person` example from docs, you could do

```
Person.objects.select_related('hometown').select_for_update(of=('self',))
```

which would lock only the `Person` object

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `select_related` with foreign keys that are nullable when you are using `select_for_update` on the same queryset.

This will work in all cases:

```
Book.objects.select_related().select_for_update().get(name='Doors of perception')
```