# Django: select_for_update() on Foreign Key Relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I've used `select_for_update()` a lot. However, in all the cases I've used it, it has been through a manager like so:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    transaction = Transaction.objects.select_for_update().get(id="12345-6789-10")
    transaction.status = StatusEnum.APPROVED
    transaction.save()
```

However, I sometimes get the transaction via a reference from another object.

For example:

```
transaction = another_object.transaction
transaction.status=StatusEnum.APPROVED
transaction.save()
```

^^ This will not lock the row. Instead, I would have to do this:

```
transaction = Transaction.objects.select_for_update().get(id=another_object.transaction.id)
```

My question: if another object has a foreign key relation to a Transaction, is there a way to lock the Transaction object without writing a get query? I understand performance-wise both options are about the same. Just looking for something a bit cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Found [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)

Comment: Thanks for this @daka. Since asking this question a few years ago I have found the appropriate way to do it using Django 2.0+. Since answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer since upgrading to Django 2.0. See this answer on GitHub:

[django select_for_update and select_related on same query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36253793/django-select-for-update-and-select-related-on-same-query)

You can use select_related with select_for_update that will lock the respective row in each table.